# Help with the natural deduction proof to the sequent ⊢ (φ → ((¬φ) → ψ))

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I am working through Chriswell and Hodge's *Mathematical Logic* and am confused by the answer to the question 2.6.2 (b).

In particular why

```
  φ        (¬φ)
──────    ────── (¬E)
        ⊥
────────────────── (RAA)
        ψ
```

is a valid derivation of ψ.

Comment: According to [this version](https://www.ibisc.univ-evry.fr/~belardinelli/Documents/Logique/Mathematical-Logic-ChiswellHodges.pdf) of Chriswell and Hodge's _Mathematical Logic_, Exercise 2.6.2 asks for a proof of $\vdash ((\lnot (\varphi \to \psi)) \to \varphi)$, not of $\vdash (\varphi \to ((\lnot \varphi)\to \psi))$.

Comment: Anyway, your derivation is not a proof of $\vdash \psi$ but a proof of $\varphi, \lnot \varphi \vdash \psi$, i.e. a derivation of $\psi$ under the assumptions $\varphi$ and $\lnot \varphi$ (the instance of the rule RAA does not discharge any assumption in this case).

Comment: See page 24 for $(\lnot \text {-E})$ rule and page 26 for $(\text{RAA})$ rule.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Thanks for pointing out that I've got the wrong question and also for clarifying that the derivation is of not ⊢ψ but of φ,¬φ⊢ψ. I knew the question I was working on but accidentally typed in the question from the row above. I'll create a new question and correcly formulate it.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks! I'll go and review those pages again.